# Pie loader 2 progress colors, css, html, javascript

Tags: css, html, reactjs, pie-chart, css3pie

I almost finished timeout timer using ReactJS. It should look like a pie loader and I need at the last 30% of progress to change color from green to yellow.

As a template for timer I took http://jsfiddle.net/Aw5Rf/7/ this one.

```
<div class="pie" data-percent="22">
    <div class="left">
        <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple possibility would be to add and remove a class based on the progress:

http://jsfiddle.net/Aw5Rf/139/

**javascript:**

```
$(".pie").each(function() {
    var percent = $(this).data("percent"),
        $left = $(this).find(".left span"),
        $right = $(this).find(".right span"),
        deg;

    if(percent >= 70) {
        this.classList.add("pie-almostComplete");
    } else {
        this.classList.remove("pie-almostComplete");
    }
    ...
}
```

**css:**

```
.pie-almostComplete {
    background-color: rgb(255, 207, 51);
}
```